# Date Offset in pandas data range

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following formula which get me EOM date every 3M starting Feb 90.

dates = pd.date_range(start="1990-02-01", end="2029-09-30", freq="3M")

I am looking to get in a condensed manner the same table but where the dates are offset by x business days.
This mean, if x = 2, 2 business days before the EOM date calculated every 3M starting Feb 90.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

x = 2 
dates = pd.date_range(start="1990-02-01", end="2029-09-30", freq="3M") - BDay(x)
```

```py
>>> dates
DatetimeIndex(['1990-02-26', '1990-05-29', '1990-08-29', '1990-11-28',
               '1991-02-26', '1991-05-29', '1991-08-29', '1991-11-28',
               '1992-02-27', '1992-05-28',
               ...
               '2027-05-27', '2027-08-27', '2027-11-26', '2028-02-25',
               '2028-05-29', '2028-08-29', '2028-11-28', '2029-02-26',
               '2029-05-29', '2029-08-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=159, freq=None)
```

**Example**

```py
x = 2

dti1 = pd.date_range(start="1990-02-01", end="2029-09-30", freq="3M")
dti2 = pd.date_range(start="1990-02-01", end="2029-09-30", freq="3M") - BDay(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({"dti1": dti1.day_name(), "dti2": dti2.day_name()})
```

```py
>>> df.head(20)
         dti1       dti2
0   Wednesday     Monday
1    Thursday    Tuesday
2      Friday  Wednesday
3      Friday  Wednesday
4    Thursday    Tuesday
5      Friday  Wednesday
6    Saturday   Thursday
7    Saturday   Thursday
8    Saturday   Thursday
9      Sunday   Thursday
10     Monday   Thursday
11     Monday   Thursday
12     Sunday   Thursday
13     Monday   Thursday
14    Tuesday     Friday
15    Tuesday     Friday
16     Monday   Thursday
17    Tuesday     Friday
18  Wednesday     Monday
19  Wednesday     Monday
```